# php blocking visitors based on text list of ips

Tags: php, while-loop, ip-blocking

I'm trying to write a SIMPLE generic block of PHP include code that will read a text file to fill an array of IPs, then use that array to compare a visitors IP to determine if it should end display of the page, **blocking** that page or site. This code also drops a log line to a 403 file and then sends the loser (user) to view it, ending their visit to the site. the line appends their info to the end of the open ended 403 file.

The include can be put in anywhere you don't want that list of IPs to see. The problem is I'm a hopeless hack, and don't have a good grasp on these loops and the syntax. can you help me sort this out? it seems to read the IP list ok, but then the while loop seems to be wrong. I could prolly simplify this more. but I'm not sure what the issue is.. My choice of variable names... maybe.

```
<? 
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


        $link_file = "bannedips.dat";
        $lines = file($link_file);

        foreach($lines as $line){
            if(!empty($line)){
                $line_array = explode(',', $line);
                $bannedip = trim(trim(strip_tags($line_array[0]), "\x00..\x1F"));
            }
        }



while $bannedip if ((substr($IP,0,10) == $bannedip) {
$line = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " - <b>$IP</b><br>\n";

file_put_contents('403.shtml', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
header('Location: 403.shtml');
die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Any reason for doing this in PHP and not just in your firewall or web server settings?

Comment: you don't need to put in while loop you can simply put those ips in array from file then find the visitor ip exist in array or not.....simple !!!!

Comment: I have another page that I use to create the IP list, as I remove content placed from those IPs.

That is what I would like to see, the code that finds the ip in the array. are we talking about using somethign as simple as 'if (in_array'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build up an array of the banned IP's from the file (you are just overwriting the last one in your code, use `$bannedip[]` to add it to a list) and then use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check the users IP against this list...

```
$link_file = "bannedips.dat";
$lines = file($link_file);
$bannedip = [];   // Create start array
foreach($lines as $line){
    if(!empty($line)){
        $line_array = explode(',', $line);
        $bannedip[] = trim(trim(strip_tags($line_array[0]), "\x00..\x1F"));
    }
}
if(in_array($IP, $bannedip )) {
    $line = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " - <b>$IP</b><br>\n";
    file_put_contents('403.shtml', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    header('Location: 403.shtml');
    die();
}
```

There may be a tidier way of dealing with the input file, but without knowing the format it's difficult to say, so I've left your code as it was.

**Update:**

If you banned IP file is just a list of IP addresses, you could replace the load and `foreach` with...

```
$bannedip = file($link_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$bannedip = array_filter($bannedip);
```

**Update2:**
As you seem to have sorted this out yourself, but posted a sample of the actual file format you have, thought I would add how it could be done...

```
$IP= "31.130.4.241";
$link_file = "bannedips.dat";
$bannedip = file($link_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$bannedip = array_map("str_getcsv", $bannedip);
$bannedip = array_column($bannedip, null, 0);
if(isset($bannedip[$IP])) {
    $line = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " - <b>{$bannedip[$IP][0]}</b> - {$bannedip[$IP][1]} - {$bannedip[$IP][2]}<br>\n";
    file_put_contents('403.shtml', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    header('Location: 403.shtml');
    die();
}
```

Comment: That looks great - the data format is just a list of IP addresses.

Comment: You could try the added code which simplifies the load part, so assuming that it's just an IP per line of file it will be a lot quicker.

Comment: it's odd, but the If is not finding the IP in the array, and not triggering the write to the 403 or redirecting. I will try the latest suggestion, perhaps the array is not building right. Nope - that didn't help either... I've placed my own IP in the list, and testing from my dev machine. it should reject the visit, but nope. this should work as a PHP include, anywhere , for anyone, based on a text file of IPs. but I'm still struggling. I've put it as the last thing in my header. perhaps it should be first?

Comment: it won't let me post it that way I have it. one IP per line.

Comment: BTW, I really appreciate your input...!

Comment: I may have made a mistake, can you change the line `if(in_array($IP, $bannedip )) {` ( It was a lower case $ip).

Comment: here is what I have now:<? 
 $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
ECHO $IP;
  
        $link_file = "bannedips.dat";
        $lines = file($link_file);

        $bannedip = file($link_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
  $bannedip = array_filter($bannedip);

  


  if(in_array($IP, $bannedip )) {
   $line = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " - <b>$IP</b><br>\n";
   file_put_contents('403.shtml', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
   header('Location: 403.shtml');
  ECHO 'FOUND';
   die();

  }
  ECHO ' - NOT FOUND';
?>

Comment: Can you add - `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the start, it may help with some more information as to what is happening.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: not yet, and I can't figure out how to post what I've got currently so it retains the format.I tried the 4 space indent...

Comment: Fixed. Trigger had an extra space I didn't see, now it is working. thank you!

Comment: So I finally managed to make this work as I originally intended. the data file now consists of 3 data fields; IP, Ref Site and Email address. it opens the file and as it loads checks each line for a match, and if it find it, stops and ends, posting the result to the 403 page and redirecting the loser there. Finally an end to these spammers. this way they can reference each other and spam one another - www.yosquirt.com/403.shtml

Comment: Decided to add a new version of the code now you have given the proper file format.

Comment: Nice and short. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

The original goal was write a short piece of INCLUDE code that would parse a text file, find a matching IP, log the info, and drop the spamming jerk to a 403 page. this way, an offending user COULD visit any page, except ones that included this piece of script. Very selective blocking.

Here is my final code:

```
  <? 
    $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    echo $IP;
    $link_file = "bannedips.dat";
    $lines = file($link_file);

            foreach($lines as $line){
                if(!empty($line)){
                    $line_array = explode(',', $line);
                    $inputip = trim(trim(strip_tags($line_array[0]), "\x00..\x1F"));
                    $website = trim(trim(strip_tags($line_array[1]), "\x00..\x1F"));
                    $email = trim(trim(strip_tags($line_array[2]), "\x00..\x1F"));

                    if($IP == $inputip) {
                        $line = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " - <b>$inputip</b> - $website - $email<br>\n";
                        file_put_contents('403.shtml', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
                        header('Location: 403.shtml');
                        die();
                    }
                }
            }
    ?>
```

The data file format is as follows:

```
23.105.159.238,penilengorgement.com,randomjerk@spammer.net
31.130.4.240,scamtown.com,spameister@viagraads.com
```

so, now as I ban IPs (spammers), it pulls their info from my blog, and drops it into the linkfile, where it can be parsed and used to log repeat offenders and offer them an alternative to trying to get into my site, by offering them a list of their peers.